# Class property not returning right datetime format

Tags: asp.net, datetime, properties, format

Why doesn´t this property return a datetime formated with the following pattern when using the property in the codebehind page in my ASP.NET Webforms website? When debugging i can see that the value the returning datetime is "2011-02-21 16:13:29.670" wich is correct.

```
Public Property UserLastUpdated() As DateTime
    Get
        Return _userLastUpdated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DateTime)
        _userLastUpdated = value
    End Set
End Property
```

But when i look at the returned value in the codebehind page i get this value

```
objUser.UserLastUpdated = #2/21/2011 4:13:29 PM#
```

And after assigning the returned property value to a hiddenfield in the .aspx page i get this value assign to the hiddenfield.value "2011-02-21 16:13:29"

```
hdnUserLastUpdated.Value = objUser.UserLastUpdated
```

Comment: The property in the second code chunk is `UserLastUpdated` which is different to the one in the first code chunk `UserCreated`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to switch the return type of   `UserCreated()` to string since the `Get` is actually returning a formatted string and not a `DateTime` instance or you could keep it as a DateTime type and not do the formatting in the getter. You could do the formatting when you are assigning it to the hidden field value

```
hdnUserLastUpdated.Value = objUser.UserLastUpdated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
```